# Classification accuracy

Tags: machine-learning

While solving multi class classification problems in one vs all manner.how the accuracy of classifier is computed for the entire data set.
If say for class 1accuracy is 77 for class 2 it's 70 and for class 3 it's 88.then what will be the accuracy for the entire data set.

Answer (score 0):

You don't calculate accuracy for each class separately. You evaluate the overall performance of your model. One way to measure accuracy in multiclass classification, is to count the number of fails in predicting the class for your data set. For example, your training set has 100 examples. To find the accuracy in predicting the training set, you predict the class for each of the examples. You count the numbwr of fails in predicting the classes. Let's say you failed in predicting 20 examples. Then the accuracy of your model on the training set is 80%.

Comment: M treating multi class data set in one vs all manner.then how accuracy is reported?